# Best method for having single editor fields in an Enumerable form?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form, that just runs through a model and returns all the rows,. pretty basic MVC one:

```
@model IEnumerable<Something.Else.Model>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor()</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor()</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, what I want is to load an editor row when a button is clicked, and the editor fields to reference the model because of the validation I have on the model.

```
@model IEnumerable<Something.Else.Model>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor()</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor()</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: none">   // editor row
            <td>@Html.EditorFor()</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox()</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue I am having is that the form is Enumerable, so when I try to load a single row i get the message IEnumerable does not contain a definition for "field name" and no extension method etc etc

I know I could use @Html.Editor instead of editor for, but I have a lot of validation on the model I want to use.  I could put these rows in the @foreach section and load the top one and use jquery to clear the values but that seems like a bad way.

The purpose of this is to enter a new line, not edit an existing one.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to replace `foreach` with `for` with indexing of items, add a placeholder (empty) item at the end of the collection and display the editing item on button click:

```
@model List<Something.Else.Model>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Second)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="edit-item" style='display: none'>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[Model.Count - 1].First)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[Model.Count - 1].Second)
            </td>
        </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count - 1; i++) // the last item is the placeholder (editing item)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Mode[i].First)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Mode[i].First)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Mode[i].Second)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Mode[i].Second)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Model type is changed to `List` to allow indexing of items.
The controller would need to determine from the values in the placeholder if the placeholder is filled (an item was entered).

Comment: The button would be at the top of the page, the jquery part to load the hidden row etc I'm fine with.  What I want though, is a to load a signal editor row to enter a new line, not amend an existing one

Comment: I haven't used List in the view before, Assuming my model is Just fIrstName and Second Name, how do i structure it to pull through in the view as a List?  Is there any additional code i need to at to the controller?

Comment: I think i have it, mostly, was it view models you were talking about? :)

Comment: yes, it was the type of the view model - from IEnumerable to List